# behaviour difference explainaion request of bw VB6 and C# CryptAcquireContext

Tags: c#, vb6

I am at odds with the behavior of following code, mostly because I am not well versed with VB6. My VB declarations

```
MS_DEF_PROV_A ="Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
PROV_RSA_FULL=1
CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT== &HF0000000
```

C# Declarations

```
const string MS_DEF_PROV = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
uint PROV_RSA_FULL = 1;
public const uint CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = 0xF0000000;
```

now when I run the following code

```
CryptAcquireContext(out hProv, null, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
```

And set a break point here, I see that variable in C#

```
CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = 4026531840
```

While on the VB side it has value of

```
CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = -268435456
```

I just wonder why is this discrepancy, shouldn't it be the same value..both values are on the same computer, just different IDEs..It might not be anything, but since I don't know much so want to understand the difference in behavior..

Thanks

Comment: Your declaration of CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT is usng a test (==) so probably not declared at all.

Comment: Just convert the number to hex with the Windows calculator in Programmer mode.  4026531840 == 0xF0000000, -268435456 == 0xF0000000.  The same number, the latter one is an *int* instead of a *uint*.

Answer (score 2):

VB6 only supports signed 32 bit numbers. To the function recieving the number the bits are the same.